# Creating an accurate php search engine to search database

Tags: php

Ok, I attempted at making my own search function which doesnt work very well.

It consists of eliminating useless words such as "how" "you" "to" then using a premade Stemmer class that reduces words to their root so "Appointments" searches "appoint"

However in the end I'm really only searching keywords and the results are not very accurate.

Are there open source search engines that i can implement for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen implementation of the Lucene Search engine in PHP using the `Zend_Search_Lucene` class, which obviously uses the Zend Framework library, check out a few links.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

http://devzone.zend.com/article/91

http://ifacethoughts.net/2008/02/07/zend-brings-lucene-to-php/

Comment: im using this with Flex so as long as it outputs through an array im good.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/). It was originally for Java but I believe there is a PHP version in the Zend framework.

**Edit:** 
Here's the [reference guide in Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) and a [guide to using it](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/91).